# Why Aviary is returning scaled down image back?

Tags: android, aviary

I am using Aviary SDK as a photo editor in my app but it is scaling down my images.
Consider I am passing an image of size `720*720` but after editing Aviary is giving me image of size `720*590`

Why Aviary is returning scaled down image back?

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent( ShowCapturedImage.this, FeatherActivity.class );
newIntent.setData(Uri.fromFile(pictureFile) );
startActivityForResult( newIntent, 1 );
```

Comment: ["By default, the Aviary editor works on a medium resolution image in order to speed up.."](https://developers.aviary.com/docs/android/setup-guide#toc_15) maybe?

Comment: @zapl I tried this but no use`newIntent.putExtra( Constants.EXTRA_IN_HIRES_MEGAPIXELS, MegaPixels.Mp3.ordinal() );`

Answer (score 2):

Finally Got the solution. It is mentioned in Aviary android sample app

```
final DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics( metrics );
        int max_size = Math.max( metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels );
        max_size = (int) ( (float) max_size / 1.2f );
        newIntent.putExtra( Constants.EXTRA_MAX_IMAGE_SIZE, max_size );
```

Comment: in which package is `Constants` class? Can't find it, may I be missing an additional dependency?